# Make image draggable between two scrollables

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coordinate-transformation

I have two different panels:

[image: panels]

Here's the tree:

[image: tree]

In those panels, I want the user to be able to clic on the images on the left, and to drag them on the right.

You can find tons of Unity "basic" UI dragndrop tutorials, but they all do the same: you can drag and drop between elements that are in the same panel.

My problem is that they are in different panels, so I can't drag'n drop easily from one panel to another one.

For now **I'm just trying to make the drag principle working inside the `PanelBoatsToDrag`**: being able to click on an `Image`, and being able to drag it *into* the `PanelBoatsToDrag`.

Each `Image` is made from a prefab. I've added a `DragHandler.cs` script file to that prefab, it should handle that. Here it is:

```
public class DragHandler : MonoBehaviour, IBeginDragHandler, IDragHandler, IEndDragHandler
{

    public static GameObject itemBeingDragged;
    private Vector3 startPosition;

    public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        itemBeingDragged = gameObject;
        startPosition = transform.position;
        Debug.Log("OnBeginDrag\n" +
            "eventData = " + eventData +
            "\nInput.mousePosition = " + Input.mousePosition +
            "\nCamera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) = " +
            Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition));
    }

    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        transform.position = Input.mousePosition;
    }

    public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        itemBeingDragged = null;
        transform.position = startPosition;
        Debug.Log("OnEndDrag");
    }
}
```

The `OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)` code doesn't work at all. I need to convert the mouse coordinates to the local coordinate of the `Image` being clicked and assign that to the Image. How to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity supports also a method `OnDrop()`. If I were you I would approach it that way. While starting dragging `OnBeginDrag()` you should do 2 things: Move your object higher in hierarchy by setting its parent to `PanelMiddle` so it will be drawn over everything else AND `this.GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().blocksRaycasts = false;` so you won't raycast into it.
After that it should be simple:

```
public void OnDrop(PointerEventData eventData)
{
GameObject dropedItem = eventData.pointerDrag.GetComponent<GameObject>();

if (isEmpty) // you have space for this object
{

  dropedItem.transform.SetParent(this.transform);
  dropedItem.transform.position = //set to any position you need
  dropedItem.GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().blocksRaycasts = true; //so you can pick this item again
}
else
{
  //return it to old position and to old parent
}
}
```

Method `OnDrop()` should be attached to the panel or some kind of a slot you want to drag items to.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! But... it doesnt really answer to my question - or maybe I didn't express myself properly. I need to convert the coordinates of the mouse (`Input.mousePosition`) to the coordinates of the `PanelMiddle`.  This is my main problem.

Comment: FYI if that can help, my `RenderMode` is set `ScreenSpaceCamera`, and I cant change that because I'm using 3D models on a 2D scene.

Comment: Could you tell me why do you need to convert the coordinates? From what see I understand that you want your object to be draggable from 1 panel to another right?

Comment: Here's the how user interaction should be: (1) the user clicks on a boat. (2) the boats stays here but (2a) all the background becomes black except the "destination board" that is on the right (2b) there's a highlighted version of the boat that is draggable (3) I have not even thought about how to do this: when the boat that is dragged comes over the board, there's another third "transparent" light boat that comes at the "grid" position so the user knows that if he drop the boat here it will come in the "transparent" light boat position.

Comment: I know what I want is hard to do but I dont want any other workaround. I really want the user to feel the freedom of movement = both (drag the boat everywhere **and** to see clearly where he can put it, and to be able to see if he drops the boat where this boat will actually be put).

Comment: For the note, I really didn't think that making such an a easy game would be that hard: it's not about Unity or Unreal Engine, it's about making interactions exactly the way I want + find the good documentation with Unity (50% of the Unity documentation is poor or un-documented or no sample) + do the right maths to have everything working.

Comment: I'll check your answer as valid + add my own answer (I made this work) when I reboot under Windows (yep dat crappy unsafe OS, not choice, thanks Unity (Linux version is in alpha (they say it's beta but it's closer to alpha (IMHO))))

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it, I let the only important part of my class here:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class DragHandler : MonoBehaviour,
    IBeginDragHandler, IDragHandler, IEndDragHandler
{
    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        CanvasScaler scaler = GetComponentInParent<CanvasScaler>();
        Vector3 i_scale = itemBeingDragged.transform.localScale;
        RectTransform rt = itemBeingDragged.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        Rect r = rt.rect;
        /**
         * Explanation: to center the object we need its width+height:
         * Resize width to the current scale = r.width * i_scale.x 
         * Divide by 2 to get the center we have: (r.width * i_scale.x / 2)
         * Same for y.
         * 
         * Calculate the coords of the mouse proportional to the screen scale:
         */
        rt.anchoredPosition = new Vector2(
            (Input.mousePosition.x * scale_x) - (r.width * i_scale.x / 2),
            (Input.mousePosition.y * scale_y) - (r.height * i_scale.y / 2));
        // everybody tells me to apply this but it doesn't work:
        // itemBeingDragged.GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().blocksRaycasts = true;
    }

}
```